# What's the purpose of the code on the painting in The Cistern?

Tags: god-of-war-ascension

I was playing when I saw a painting with a code in a room in The Cistern.

> Of all the prophecies I have seen, this one haunts my dreams
>
> QUJIKPHIUEEEKMJQUJ
>
> The full truth of this nightmare yet remains hidden.  -Aletheia

Where do I have to enter it and what does it do?

Comment: Acording to [this](http://www.ign.com/wikis/god-of-war-ascension/Cistern_Painting_Code_(QUJIKPHIUEEEKMJQUJ)) it could be a reference to future God of War games

Comment: You should post that as the answer Cresh. I think that's about as much information as we're going to get.

Comment: Well... if someone wants to put this comment has an answer, he will get extra credits :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.ign.com/wikis/god-of-war-ascension/Cistern_Painting_Code_%28QUJIKPHIUEEEKMJQUJ%29) sums it up pretty well. (Credit to Cresh for the find)

Thanks to the sleuths at IGN, the message has been deciphered. It reads:

> SUN BIRD BULL LION SUN

If you stand near each of symbols on the ground that correspond to these words in the area around the painting and press R1, the painting changes to a different message, which reads:

> When the earth stops, the journey begins...

The most obvious meaning behind this is a reference to the next game, but that may not be true.

Some have theorized that the words "Sun, bird, etc" are referencing Egyptian mythology, which may hint at the next game taking place in Egypt.